# Generating ARB file in intl package does not escape escaped characters

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

Below is the plural message being used. But, when generating the ARB file, the single quote is not escaping. Similary, I also used double quotes to use the single quotes. That didn't give desired result  either.

```dart
Intl.plural(
        numberOfOranges,
        zero: "You\'ve got zero orange.",
        one: "You\'ve got $numberOfOranges orange.",
        other: "You\'ve got $numberOfOranges oranges.",
        name: 'getOrangesText',
        args: [numberOfOranges],
      )
```

ARB: app_en.arb

```json
{
  "@@last_modified": "2021-12-23T12:15:56.804292",
  "appTitle": "Home",
  "@appTitle": {
    "description": "Application title/name",
    "type": "text",
    "placeholders": {}
  },
  "helloWorld": "Hello World!",
  "@helloWorld": {
    "description": "Hello World message",
    "type": "text",
    "placeholders": {}
  },
  "getOrangesText": "{numberOfOranges,plural, =0{You''ve got zero orange.}=1{You''ve got {numberOfOranges} orange.}other{You''ve got {numberOfOranges} oranges.}}",
  "@getOrangesText": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholders": {
      "numberOfOranges": {}
    }
  }
}
```